# the limit of absolute value is the absolute value of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let A $\subset$ $\Bbb R$, let $f$: A $\to$ $\Bbb R$ and let $c$  $\in$  $\Bbb R$ a acumulation point of A. If $\lim_{x\to c} f$ exist and if $|f|$ is the function defined for $x$ $\in$ A, by  $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$, then prove that  $\lim_{x\to c} |f| =$  $\ $|$ lim_{x\to c} f $|$ $

I have the idea to prove it, with the triangular inequality, but... it's not clear to me.

Edit: This is the proof

Let $L$= $\lim_{x\to c} f$, by definition of limit, for all $\epsilon > 0$, exist $\delta >0$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta $ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, now, by triangular inequality $||f(x)|-|L||<|f(x)-L|$, so, when $|x-c|<\delta $, $||f(x)|-|L||<|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, so , $\lim_{x\to c} |f| = |L| $ and $\lim_{x\to c} |f| =$  $\ $|$ lim_{x\to c} f $|$ $

Comment: Write up what you do have, and people will be much more willing to help you.

Comment: sorry, i edit the question with the proof

Comment: Your proof is correct. Do note that $||x|-|y||\le |x-y|$, the inequality need not be strict.